# How to Generate This MySQL Code In Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysql

This is my MySQL code. I am new to Codeigniter.

```
SELECT
    a.school_code,
    b.Us_News_Ranking,
    b.School_Name,
    COUNT( * ) AS LSN_APPLICATIONS,
    COUNT( a.status ) AS STATUS,
    COUNT( 
        CASE
            WHEN a.status =  'w'
            THEN a.status
        END
    ) AS accp_rate,
    COUNT( 
        CASE
            WHEN a.status =  'Intend_to_apply'
            THEN a.status
        END
    ) AS accp_rate2,
    AVG( CAST( a.Med_LSAT AS DECIMAL( 12, 2 ) ) ) AS MEd_LSAT,
    AVG( CAST( a.Med_GPA AS DECIMAL( 12, 2 ) ) ) AS MEd_GPA
FROM user_application a, lawscools b
WHERE a.school_code = b.school_code
GROUP BY school_code
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Looks like there's part of your query missing...

Comment: I assume you mean in Active Record? You can keep that code as is and run it in $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY HERE")

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query function

```
$this->db->query('SQL_CODE');
```

Well.. I guess there's another way too but why not? :)